# Need to sum of last column based on pipe delimiter

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have below inputs with huge number of rows

```
11|ABCD|19900101123123445455|555|AAA|50505050|0000009030
11|ABCD|19900101123123445455|555|AAA|50505050|0000000199
13|ABCD|201803010YYY66666666|600|ETC|20180300|0000084099
11|ABCD|19900101123123445455|555|AAA|50505050|0008995001
```

And I need to get below output

```
11|ABCD|19900101123123445455|555|AAA|50505050|9004230
13|ABCD|201803010YYY66666666|600|ETC|20180300|84099
```

I have been trying with below awk but having too limited knowledge with arrays.

```
cat test|awk -F"|" '{ a[$1]++;b[$2]++;c[$3]++;d[$4]++;e[$5]++;f[$6]+=$6 }; END { for (i in a); print i, f[i]}'
```

I need to sum last column of column number 6 and print all first 5 columns, which are separated by pipe and last 6th column as sum of 6th column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }
     { a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6] += $7 }
     END{ for (i in a) print i, a[i] }' file
```

The output:

```
11|ABCD|19900101123123445455|555|AAA|50505050|9004230
13|ABCD|201803010YYY66666666|600|ETC|20180300|84099
```

Answer (score 9):

With **GNU** `datamash` command:

```
$ datamash -t'|' -s -g 1,2,3,4,5,6 sum 7 < infile
11|ABCD|19900101123123445455|555|AAA|50505050|9004230
13|ABCD|201803010YYY66666666|600|ETC|20180300|8409
```

In [`datamash v1.2+`](https://fossies.org/diffs/datamash/1.1.1_vs_1.2/NEWS-diff.html), you can specify the columns range also.

```
$ datamash -t'|' -s -g 1-6 sum 7 < infile
```

Or shortest **`AWK`** alternative and where you had **N** columns and you should not specify all one by one:

```
awk -F'|' '{x=$NF;NF--; a[$0]+=x} END{for(i in a) print i, a[i]}' OFS='|' infile
```

Answer (score 4):

The idea is right, but for such a requirement you create the hash key as the values except the last column and use that key to sum up values in the last column. Once all the lines are processed in the `END` clause we print the summed up values

```
awk '
     BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} {
         hashKey = ""
         for(i=1;i<=(NF-1); i++) {
             hashKey = ( hashKey ? (hashKey FS $i):$i )
         }
         total[hashKey]+=$NF
     }
     END { for ( j in total ) print j, total[j] }
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

and perl

```
perl -lne '
    $sum{$1} += $2 if /(.*)\|(.*)/
 } END {
    print "$_|$sum{$_}" for keys %sum
' file
```